# How much rep would Jon Skeet have if there was no rep limit?

Tags: discussion, reputation, fun

Just curious about this, but how much rep would he currently have if there was no daily rep cap of 200?

Comment: How much Rep would a Jon Skeet have if a Jon Skeet couldn't be capped? (sung to the tune of "How much wood would a woodchuck chuck...")

Comment: This is available via Data Explorer: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/161622/how-much-rep-would-i-have-without-rep-cap?UserId=22656 (currently 2712265, without bounties)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To save us from copy cat questions here we go: (based off most recent data dump so its not super accurate)

#### User                           UncappedRep Reputation     Loss

```
Jon Skeet              367651      118596     67.74 
Marc Gravell           170012      96095      43.48 
JaredPar               104431      67345      35.51 
Alex Martelli          100348      52804      47.38 
cletus                 99143       69976      29.42 
Mehrdad Afshari        93497       60582      35.20 
tvanfosson             91962       76569      16.74 
Greg Hewgill           91059       67038      26.38 
Joel Coehoorn          82284       60474      26.51 
S.Lott                 74845       62476      16.53 
paxdiablo              74403       60439      18.77 
Johannes Schaub - litb 71294       53015      25.64 
Andrew Hare            65849       46017      30.12 
Neil Butterworth       63050       36332      42.38 
Konrad Rudolph         60729       50958      16.09 
Reed Copsey            59266       44255      25.33 
CMS                    56207       50297      10.51 
Paolo Bergantino       53811       39134      27.28 
VonC                   53057       50445      4.92  
Bill the Lizard        50363       46600      7.47  
Greg                   48976       43005      12.19 
Quassnoi               46302       37444      19.13 
Gumbo                  46223       41797      9.58  
Brian R. Bondy         45547       36633      19.57 
Adam Rosenfield        45173       40387      10.59 
jalf                   44338       38969      12.11 
Mitch Wheat            43986       40415      8.12  
chaos                  40375       34198      15.30 
Bill Karwin            40148       38205      4.84  
marc_s                 39462       34102      13.58 
Vinko Vrsalovic        39440       35522      9.93  
Michael Burr           39366       36206      8.03  
Tomalak                39195       36504      6.87  
bobince                38892       34163      12.16 
Jonathan Leffler       37949       37006      2.48  
RichieHindle           37244       27450      26.30 
nickf                  36890       32868      10.90 
John Saunders          35742       28844      19.30 
Lasse V. Karlsen       34775       33055      4.95  
Rex M                  34497       29449      14.63 
Adam Davis             34308       28375      17.29 
Paul Dixon             33852       31587      6.69  
Guffa                  33106       31067      6.16  
Paul Tomblin           32457       30730      5.32  
Brian Agnew            31887       29391      7.83  
unwind                 31403       28276      9.96  
FlySwat                30244       23068      23.73 
Charlie Martin         30160       26499      12.14 
Sinan Ünür             29615       22494      24.05 
Michael Borgwardt      29585       27127      8.31  
Aaron Digulla          29067       25463      12.40 
sylvarking             28924       27445      5.11  
Jason Baker            28465       24839      12.74 
Robert Harvey          28436       26070      8.32  
Pascal MARTIN          28103       20184      28.18 
AnthonyWJones          28066       26888      4.20  
Steven A. Lowe         27928       26306      5.81  
Darin Dimitrov         27839       25440      8.62  
karim79                27703       23441      15.38 
duffymo                27634       27293      1.23  
1800 INFORMATION       27576       25361      8.03  
John Millikin          27270       22113      18.91 
Norman Ramsey          27249       26393      3.14  
Pavel Minaev           27232       19151      29.67 
Noldorin               27140       23412      13.74 
Thomas Owens           26755       22704      15.14 
Fredrik Mörk           26381       22548      14.53 
brian d foy            25877       24094      6.89  
unknown                25865       23457      9.31  
Matt Hamilton          25603       25964      -1.41 
Michael Stum           25434       25669      -0.92 
Steve Jessop           25117       23954      4.63  
Martin v. Löwis        25101       22540      10.20 
skaffman               25007       23095      7.65  
Johannes Rössel        24961       23346      6.47  
dirkgently             24933       19512      21.74 
Charles Bailey         24470       22539      7.89  
mmyers                 24234       22041      9.05  
Earwicker              24180       21881      9.51  
Martin York            24093       24316      -0.93 
Kent Boogaart          23776       22368      5.92  
Uri                    23678       23471      0.87  
ocdecio                23593       21528      8.75  
Remus Rusanu           23265       22257      4.33  
John Feminella         23156       17190      25.76 
Will                   23052       23462      -1.78 
Chris Jester-Young     23046       21547      6.50  
Tom Hawtin - tackline  22510       20873      7.27  
Shog9                  22370       23235      -3.87 
Jonathan Sampson       22334       16076      28.02 
Brian Rasmussen        22316       20370      8.72  
Brian                  21866       22019      -0.70 
Craig Stuntz           21818       21867      -0.22 
aku                    21800       17480      19.82 
James Curran           21777       19107      12.26 
gbn                    21599       21352      1.14  
Ólafur Waage           21557       21201      1.65  
Gulzar                 21424       20758      3.11  
Gamecat                21402       21592      -0.89
```

SQL:

```
select top 100 OwnerUserId as UserId, 
    SUM(case 
    when VoteTypeId = 3 then -2 
    when VoteTypeId = 2 then 10 
    else 15
    end) as UncappedRep  
into #totals
from Posts p
    join Votes on PostId = p.id 
where CommunityOwnedDate is null 
group by OwnerUserId
order by UncappedRep desc

select UserId, Users.DisplayName as UserName, UncappedRep, Reputation,  Cast(( UncappedRep - Reputation) / (UncappedRep + 0.0) * 100.0 as numeric(4,2)) as Loss  
into #t
from Users
join #totals on UserId = id

exec spShog9
```

Comment: the negatives are probably people who had some big breaks with stuff that has since become community wiki

Comment: `order by Loss desc` would've been more fun.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea I'd hit the cap often enough to lose 2200 points.

Comment: Also I forgot to account for bounties .. so that may make the numbers slightly lower

Comment: how do some people have negative losses

Answer (score 33):

## ∞

Comment: @Shadow revision history shows rev 1 (Jeff's orginal answer), and rev 2 (you rolling back to rev 1) .....???

Comment: @Shokhet Jeff used his diamond to nuke a useless edit.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Aha. Where can I get one of those diamonds? :P

Comment: @Shokhet well, there are some jobs available [here](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/stack-exchange) if you want... employees get free diamonds as far as I can tell. :D

Comment: @ShadowWizard Very tempting..... :)

Answer (score 12):

Somewhere in the order of 330k, excluding accepted answers (I'd guess 2000 * 15, call it another 30k), bounty (maybe another 5k?), and down-votes (both given and received). The 330k is based on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?sort=stats&pagesize=50), which lists 32,933 non-wiki upvotes.

Comment: A good estimate, although the tag stats represent the total upvotes minus the total downvotes (i.e. a total score of 95 could be 100 upvotes and 5 downvotes).

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE 2020:

Jon Skeet currently has 4775054 uncapped reputation

[image]

Running https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/161622/how-much-rep-would-i-have-without-rep-cap?UserId=22656 he is currently a

Comment: I think you accidentally

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I see what you

Comment: @JourneymanGeek What do you

Comment: Last line seems cut off

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Yeah I

Comment: @GabrielPetersson why don't you