# Jon Skeet's Points without 200 limit?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support, stack-overflow, reputation

I just read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8086/how-to-get-over-200-reputation-points-every-day/8092#8092) post (and these too - [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268901/why-is-there-a-daily-reputation-limit-of-200-points), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22447/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-the-reputation-cap)) answering how does Jon Skeet get above 200 reps a day. I was just curious to know how much Jon Skeet's reputation would be by now (14 March 2015) without the 200 reputation limit.

How much would be the reputation of others in the highest reputation section. How large would be the gap?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/34042