# How can I find out the amount of points I have lost due to the reputation cap?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

Yesterday, I hit the reputation cap for the first time, and am not sure why I'm afraid that today I'll also hit it.

<sub>It seems that people in World Building love [superheroes fear of getting injured even when they can regen](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/118828/35041)...</sub>

Since I was about to reach the cap, I remembered that any vote after it won't give me more reputation and I got afraid of it :(.

So I wanted to know **is there any way to know if I actually have "lost" any gain of reputation due to the cap?** If it's possible I would like to see it.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation/43005#43005

Comment: I was sure this was a duplicate, but I can't find the original. I did however find [an old SEDE query that answers your question](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/876034/how-high-would-my-reputation-approximately-be-when-there-was-no-cap-or-cw) (which is why I thought there was a dupe in the first place).

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks

Comment: So, shall I delete my question or post as a duplicate? I never know what to do in this cases.

Comment: I'd leave it. I couldn't even find the duplicate I was thinking of, after all; I could be wrong and it might not exist. Even if it does, having another post pointing at it doesn't hurt.

Comment: Also related, interesting reading :) [How Much Rep Would Jon Skeet Have If There Was No Rep Limit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/34000/332286)

Comment: @SOLO wasn't aware of that query :D interesting

Comment: Huh, I wonder if that was the post I was originally thinking about (which is, of course, not a dupe after all, since the answer is the same but the question itself is different).

Comment: when I saw your link, I immediately thought of that post I linked to @SOLO ... seems that the SEDE query is a bit older than the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options I can think of:

1. As suggested in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43005/332286) you can see a "raw" summary of your reputation if you go to (in this case Worldbuilding) the following link: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/reputation

Here you can see a detailed report on the reputation you have gained/lost, the days you have repcapped, etc. You can also "see" the reputation you "lost" (or that you didn't gained, that is) in there; they will be **the ones surrounded by brackets**, similar to `[0]` or `[x]` (where x is the portion of rep you gained that the cap didn't truncate).

2. On your user profile, under the Reputation tab you can also see a detailed drop-down report where you can see the Rep gained on each day, per post. There you can see *all* votes you have received, some of those will have no `+10` associated, meaning they were votes you received *after* the repcap. For example, let's see this screenshot I took from last time I capped:

[image]

We can see that the vote on top didn't add any reputation to my profile. We can see that the one in the middle only added `+3`, probably because I was 3 away from earning 200 reps. The last vote was before the cap and had it's full value added to my rep. If we compared those votes with option 1, they would show `[0]`, `[3]`, and `(10)` respectively.

*Edit:* You can also try the SEDE query linked by @SOLO in comments: [How high would my reputation approximately be when there was no cap or CW?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/876034/how-high-would-my-reputation-approximately-be-when-there-was-no-cap-or-cw)